# EndpointIdentity does not contain a definition for CreateUpnIdentity

Tags: c#, .net-standard-2.0

When converting a class library from .NET Framework 4.6.2 to .NET Standard 2.0 i get this error: "EndpointIdentity does not contain a definition for CreateUpnIdentity". The change that i needed to make is install System.ServiceModel.Primitives. But somehow that library does not contain definition for "CreateUpnIdentity".

```
static EndpointIdentity CreateIdentity()
        {
            WindowsIdentity self = WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent();
            SecurityIdentifier sid = self.User;
            EndpointIdentity identity = null;
            if (sid.IsWellKnown(WellKnownSidType.LocalSystemSid) ||
                sid.IsWellKnown(WellKnownSidType.NetworkServiceSid) ||
                sid.IsWellKnown(WellKnownSidType.LocalServiceSid))
            {
                identity = EndpointIdentity.CreateSpnIdentity(
                    String.Format(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, "host/{0}", GetMachineName()));
            }
            else
            {
                // Need an UPN string here
                identity = EndpointIdentity.CreateUpnIdentity(self.Name);
            }
            return identity;
        }
```

Answer (score 2):

Instead of doing this:

```
identity = EndpointIdentity.CreateUpnIdentity(self.Name);
```

You can do this:

```
identity = new UpnEndpointIdentity(self.Name);
```

See here:
https://github.com/dotnet/wcf/issues/4089

Answer (score 0):

You must install [System.ServiceModel.Security](https://github.com/dotnet/wcf) nuget package and then you can use:

```
new DnsEndpointIdentity("localhost")
```